# When trying to escape apostrophe with 'gsub', I get backreference

Tags: ruby, escaping, gsub, apostrophe

I have this code:

```
"1'2".gsub("'","\\'")
```

Instead of `"1\'2"`, I get: `"122"`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `"\\'"` means the context following the match, which is `"2"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this:

```
puts "1'2".gsub("'","\\\\'")
```